# check for port availability using iphlpapi dll in nsis

Tags: windows, installation, port, nsis

Could anyone please let me know how to check for port availability using **iphlpapi dll** in nsis.

Comment: Which function do you want to call?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [Calling an external DLL using the System.dll plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Calling_an_external_DLL_using_the_System.dll_plugin) from the [NSIS wiki](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page).